# Java a large double

Tags: parsing, double

I hava a String is "**9999999999999999**" and I want to exchange it to double value.

So when I use Double.parseDouble() method, the result is **1.0E16**.
My code live this:

```
String strValue = "9999999999999999";
double value = Double.parseDouble(strValue);
System.out.println(value);
```

How parse it to get absolute value is 9,999,999,999,999,999.0? Please help me, thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

For large numbers you could use BigDecimal.

Store the value as

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("9999999999999999.0");
```

More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 0):

Only a finite subset of the rational numbers are exactly representable as doubles. 9999999999999999 is not one of them.

9999999999999999 is exactly half way between two double values, 1.0E16 and 9.999999999999998E15. Of those two, the first has a double bit pattern that ends in zero, and therefore is the correct round-to-nearest result.

In most physical measurement situations the difference is too small to matter. If the difference really does matter, but you need to do arithmetic that results in fractions, use BigDecimal.